# Trying to process 144k Rows Using Apply, but results too slow

Tags: r, naivebayes

I am writing a custom modified version of a naive Bayes in R and am running into runtime issues due to the size of data being process.  I need to process ~145k rows each with 95 elements.  I currently am using the following function to get the first step of the Naive Bayes.

```
probGen <- function(x, i)
{
  return(1/(sqrt(2*pi*sdBreakdown[i,]^2)
            *exp(-((x - meanBreakdown[i,])^2)/(2*(sdBreakdown[i,]^2)))))
}
```

In this function sdBreakdown and meanBreakdown are aggregate values for each possible solution.  Each time the apply is run we get the probabilities for each given column.  The apply is run as follows on the matrix where each row is another element we are trying to classify.

```
test.1 <- t(apply(temp,MARGIN=1,FUN=probGen, 1))
test.2 <- t(apply(temp,MARGIN=1,FUN=probGen, 2))
test.3 <- t(apply(temp,MARGIN=1,FUN=probGen, 3))
test.4 <- t(apply(temp,MARGIN=1,FUN=probGen, 4))
test.5 <- t(apply(temp,MARGIN=1,FUN=probGen, 5))
test.6 <- t(apply(temp,MARGIN=1,FUN=probGen, 6))
test.7 <- t(apply(temp,MARGIN=1,FUN=probGen, 7))
test.8 <- t(apply(temp,MARGIN=1,FUN=probGen, 8))
test.9 <- t(apply(temp,MARGIN=1,FUN=probGen, 9))
```

Here is how I am currently calling each apply.  This gives each elements probabilities for each possible classification 1-9.  I don't want to use the out of the box Naive Bayes because I am trying to get a better understanding of R and have a few potential accuracy improvements  I want to experiment with.

I'm not sure how to make this run in a more timely fashion though as coded it takes several hours and can take up to 7 or 8 if I'm actively working on other projects while it runs.

Edit:

To clarify the data in this example.

temp is the 145kx95 matrix of where each row is an item to be classified and each column is a quality represented numerically.

meanBreakdown is a 9x95 matrix each row is a different classification and each column corresponds to the mean average quality for the classification.

sdBreakdown is the same as meanBreakdown except stores standard deviation rather than mean average.

Parallel processing seems like it would work, but I didn't think(clearly I was wrong) the data set as large enough for the to be necessary.

Edit 2:  Here is the full code.  Forgive me if it is exceptionally bad R code.  I have always been a C developer so R is a big change in thinking and I've only done a handful of small projects in R to learn the ins and outs.

```
training <- read.csv(file = 'data\\train.csv', sep=',', header=T)

negativeOne <- function(x)
{
  x <- pmin(1, x)
  return(1-mean(x))
}

pullZeros <- function(x)
{
  x <- ifelse(x == 0, 1, 0)
  return(mean(x))
}

trainingSet <- function(x)
{
  x <- ifelse(x == 0, NA, x)
  return(mean(x, na.rm=T))
}
trainingSetSd <- function(x)
{
  x <- ifelse(x == 0, NA, x)
  return(sd(x, na.rm=T))
}

positiveBreakDown <- aggregate(x=training[,colnames(training)[grepl("feat",colnames(training))]],
                         by=list(training$target), FUN=trainingSet)

positiveBreakDownSd <- aggregate(x=training[,colnames(training)[grepl("feat",colnames(training))]],
                               by=list(training$target), FUN=trainingSetSd)

negativeBreakDown <- aggregate(x=training[,colnames(training)[grepl("feat",colnames(training))]],
                     by=list(training$target), FUN=negativeOne)

meanBreakdown <- positiveBreakDown[,colnames(positiveBreakDown)[grepl("feat",colnames(positiveBreakDown))]]

sdBreakdown <- positiveBreakDownSd[,colnames(positiveBreakDownSd)[grepl("feat",colnames(positiveBreakDownSd))]]

probGen <- function(x, i)
{
  return(1/(sqrt(2*pi*sdBreakdown[i,]^2)
            *exp(-((x - meanBreakdown[i,])^2)/(2*(sdBreakdown[i,]^2)))))
}

test <-  read.csv(file = 'data\\test.csv', sep=',', header=T)

PosTest <- test[,colnames(test)[grepl("feat",colnames(test))]]


NegTest <- aggregate(x=test[,colnames(test)[grepl("feat",colnames(test))]],
                  by=list(test$id), FUN=pullZeros)

NegTest$Group.1 <- NULL
temp <- PosTest

sweepTest.1 <- t(apply(temp,MARGIN=1,FUN=probGen, 1))
sweepTest.2 <- t(apply(temp,MARGIN=1,FUN=probGen, 2))
sweepTest.3 <- t(apply(temp,MARGIN=1,FUN=probGen, 3))
sweepTest.4 <- t(apply(temp,MARGIN=1,FUN=probGen, 4))
sweepTest.5 <- t(apply(temp,MARGIN=1,FUN=probGen, 5))
sweepTest.6 <- t(apply(temp,MARGIN=1,FUN=probGen, 6))
sweepTest.7 <- t(apply(temp,MARGIN=1,FUN=probGen, 7))
sweepTest.8 <- t(apply(temp,MARGIN=1,FUN=probGen, 8))
sweepTest.9 <- t(apply(temp,MARGIN=1,FUN=probGen, 9))

temp <- NegTest
temp$Group.1 <- NULL

N.sweepTest.1 <- sweep(as.matrix(temp),MARGIN=2,
                       as.numeric(negativeBreakDown[1, grepl("feat",colnames(positiveBreakDown))]),`*`)
N.sweepTest.2 <- sweep(as.matrix(temp),MARGIN=2,
                       as.numeric(negativeBreakDown[2, grepl("feat",colnames(positiveBreakDown))]),`*`)
N.sweepTest.3 <- sweep(as.matrix(temp),MARGIN=2,
                       as.numeric(negativeBreakDown[3, grepl("feat",colnames(positiveBreakDown))]),`*`)
N.sweepTest.4 <- sweep(as.matrix(temp),MARGIN=2,
                       as.numeric(negativeBreakDown[4, grepl("feat",colnames(positiveBreakDown))]),`*`)
N.sweepTest.5 <- sweep(as.matrix(temp),MARGIN=2,
                       as.numeric(negativeBreakDown[5, grepl("feat",colnames(positiveBreakDown))]),`*`)
N.sweepTest.6 <- sweep(as.matrix(temp),MARGIN=2,
                       as.numeric(negativeBreakDown[6, grepl("feat",colnames(positiveBreakDown))]),`*`)
N.sweepTest.7 <- sweep(as.matrix(temp),MARGIN=2,
                       as.numeric(negativeBreakDown[7, grepl("feat",colnames(positiveBreakDown))]),`*`)
N.sweepTest.8 <- sweep(as.matrix(temp),MARGIN=2,
                       as.numeric(negativeBreakDown[8, grepl("feat",colnames(positiveBreakDown))]),`*`)
N.sweepTest.9 <- sweep(as.matrix(temp),MARGIN=2,
                       as.numeric(negativeBreakDown[9, grepl("feat",colnames(positiveBreakDown))]),`*`)


sweepTest.1 <- (-1*(N.sweepTest.1 - 1)*sweepTest.1) + N.sweepTest.1
sweepTest.2 <- (-1*(N.sweepTest.2 - 1)*sweepTest.2) + N.sweepTest.2
sweepTest.3 <- (-1*(N.sweepTest.3 - 1)*sweepTest.3) + N.sweepTest.3
sweepTest.4 <- (-1*(N.sweepTest.4 - 1)*sweepTest.4) + N.sweepTest.4
sweepTest.5 <- (-1*(N.sweepTest.5 - 1)*sweepTest.5) + N.sweepTest.5
sweepTest.6 <- (-1*(N.sweepTest.6 - 1)*sweepTest.6) + N.sweepTest.6
sweepTest.7 <- (-1*(N.sweepTest.7 - 1)*sweepTest.7) + N.sweepTest.7
sweepTest.8 <- (-1*(N.sweepTest.8 - 1)*sweepTest.8) + N.sweepTest.8
sweepTest.9 <- (-1*(N.sweepTest.9 - 1)*sweepTest.9) + N.sweepTest.9

rm(N.sweepTest.1,N.sweepTest.2,N.sweepTest.3,N.sweepTest.4,N.sweepTest.5,N.sweepTest.6,N.sweepTest.7,N.sweepTest.8,N.sweepTest.9)

dist <- 1:9

for(i in 1:9)
{
  dist[i] <- nrow(training[training$target == paste0("Class_",i),])
}

res1 <- dist[1]*apply(t(sweepTest.1), MARGIN=2, FUN=prod)
res2 <- dist[2]*apply(t(sweepTest.2), MARGIN=2, FUN=prod)
res3 <- dist[3]*apply(t(sweepTest.3), MARGIN=2, FUN=prod)
res4 <- dist[4]*apply(t(sweepTest.4), MARGIN=2, FUN=prod)
res5 <- dist[5]*apply(t(sweepTest.5), MARGIN=2, FUN=prod)
res6 <- dist[6]*apply(t(sweepTest.6), MARGIN=2, FUN=prod)
res7 <- dist[7]*apply(t(sweepTest.7), MARGIN=2, FUN=prod)
res8 <- dist[8]*apply(t(sweepTest.8), MARGIN=2, FUN=prod)
res9 <- dist[9]*apply(t(sweepTest.9), MARGIN=2, FUN=prod)

rm(sweepTest.1,sweepTest.2,sweepTest.3,sweepTest.4,sweepTest.5,sweepTest.6,sweepTest.7,sweepTest.8,sweepTest.9)

interRes <- data.frame(Class_1 = res1, Class_2 = res2,Class_3 = res3,
                       Class_4 = res4,Class_5 = res5,Class_6 = res6,
                       Class_7 = res7,Class_8 = res8,Class_9 = res9)


rm(res1,res2,res3,res4,res5,res6,res7,res8,res9)

temp <- apply(t(interRes), MARGIN=2, FUN=sum)

tempRes <- interRes/temp

data<- data.frame(id=test$id)

data <- cbind(data,tempRes)

fname <- file.choose()
write.table(data, fname, row.names=FALSE, sep=",")
```

Comment: `apply` is basically a `for`-loop, so you need to vectorize your code to speed it up. But it's hard to help when we cannot actually run your code. What *exactly* is `temp`, `meanBreakdown`, and `sdBreakdown`. Can you edit your post provide and provide a some toy data? -- either a very small part of your data or some simulated data.

Comment: Agree with @AEBilgrau. I think you could use the `parallel` package to do this faster, but your question isn't fully clear.

Comment: @TARehman The `parallel` package certainly is an option, but 144,000 really isn't *that* many. One should be able to do it fairly fast with properly vectorized code.

Comment: I partially agree, but it's less the total number of rows and more the number of times they need to be processed, based on the classifications.

Comment: I can post the full code if you would like.  I was playing with the data from [this Kaggle competition.](https://www.kaggle.com/c/otto-group-product-classification-challenge/data)  Obviously my approach isn't any good for the problem, but I thought it would be a fun exercise.

Comment: @AEBilgrau I have added the full code and data source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to properly vectorize your code. With such a simple function, there is no need for using `apply` which is basically just a `for` loop.

First we generate some faux data:

```
rm(list = ls())
set.seed(1)
# Dimensions of data and some faux data
n <- 144000
m <- 95
temp <- matrix(rnorm(n*m), nrow = n, ncol = m)

meanBreakdown <- matrix(seq(-1, 1, l = 9*m), 9, m)  # Matrix of means
sdBreakdown <- matrix(seq(1, 2, l = 9*m), 9, m)  # Matrix of std. deviations
```

Let's time your version for a single `i = 1`. I've taken the liberty to make it more readable. Also, I think I found an error (if the function is just the Gaussian density). Anyway,

```
probGen <- function(x, means, sds) { # NOTE THAT THIS HAS CHANGED
   return(1/sqrt(2*pi*sds^2)*exp(-(1/(2*sds^2))*(x - means)^2) )
}

i <- 1
t1 <- system.time({
  res1 <- t(apply(temp, 1, probGen, mean = meanBreakdown[i,], 
                                    sds = sdBreakdown[i,]))
})
print(res1[1:5, 1:7])
#          [,1]       [,2]        [,3]       [,4]       [,5]      [,6]           [,7]
#[1,] 0.3720575 0.38038806 0.385805475 0.36747185 0.32253028 0.3008070 0.37473829
#[2,] 0.1980087 0.02837476 0.019424716 0.03520653 0.25872889 0.2223151 0.05506068
#[3,] 0.3935892 0.24920567 0.116377580 0.13580043 0.07012818 0.1682480 0.35898510
#[4,] 0.0137505 0.37288236 0.002338961 0.21928922 0.36341271 0.0250388 0.05103852
#[5,] 0.1648476 0.32981193 0.031723978 0.12681473 0.25509082 0.1959218 0.35277957
print(t1)
#   user  system elapsed 
#  3.452   0.205   3.662
```

Here's an alternative version where we utilize that matrices are stored in a column-major fashion together with R's replication rules:

```
probGen2 <- function(x, means, sds) {    
  return(t(1/sqrt(2*pi*sds^2)*exp(-(1/(2*sds^2))*(t(x) - means)^2)))
}

i <- 1
t2 <- system.time({
  res2 <- probGen2(x = temp, means = meanBreakdown[i, ],
                             sds = sdBreakdown[i, ])
})
print(res2[1:5, 1:7])
#          [,1]       [,2]        [,3]       [,4]       [,5]      [,6]       [,7]
#[1,] 0.3720575 0.38038806 0.385805475 0.36747185 0.32253028 0.3008070 0.37473829
#[2,] 0.1980087 0.02837476 0.019424716 0.03520653 0.25872889 0.2223151 0.05506068
#[3,] 0.3935892 0.24920567 0.116377580 0.13580043 0.07012818 0.1682480 0.35898510
#[4,] 0.0137505 0.37288236 0.002338961 0.21928922 0.36341271 0.0250388 0.05103852
#[5,] 0.1648476 0.32981193 0.031723978 0.12681473 0.25509082 0.1959218 0.35277957
print(t2)
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.499   0.014   0.515
```

As you can see, we already have quite of a speed-up for some very simple changes.
You can obviously combine this with parallel computations to get further speed gains.

Lastly, let's check that everything indeed is the same:

```
 all.equal(res1, res2)
 # [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Wow that is so much more efficient.  Is there anywhere I can look online to look into learning more about vectorizing my data properly?  I thought what I had done would have been the same but looking back I see I have to grab the row multiple times where as your way its grabbed once and repassed a bunch.

Comment: @BuckeyeBossK I don't have some good online references off the top of my head for that kind of thing, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `parallel` package and `mcmapply` or `mclapply` to run the `apply` calls in parallel. As written, your code is running sequentially (i.e. you have to finish all the 1 classifications before you go to 2, and so on).

From my understanding you are running the same function on the same data but with a different parameter. Rather than doing multiple `apply` calls, why not restructure the function to allow use of `mcmapply` - which lets you use the `apply` functionality, but iterating over multiple parameters.

Comment: I will look into that package.  I am pretty new to R, but I didn't think the data set was so large as to warrant parallel processing